# Don't see chrome in ubuntu even after installing it

Tags: google-chrome

I installed chrome and ran it. Then when I restarted computer it doesn't show up in the list of applications. How can I fix this? I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

To add the Chrome Browser launcher icon to the list of unity icons, try this

- perform a search for chrome - hit <kbd>Super/windows</kbd>, type chrome
- When the chrome icon appears in search, Click on it to launch the Chrome browser.
- Chrome icon should now appear in  unity sidebar
- Right click the icon and select `Lock to launcher`

It should now be fixed into the unity launcher